# Remove property added from "style" tag

Tags: javascript

I have a following static HTML file:

```html
<style>
  p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
  }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p>Here goes some text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="disableOverflowWrap">
  <label for="disableOverflowWrap">Disable p { overflow-wrap: break-word; }</label>
</div>
```

How is it possible to add an event listener to the check box, so that the check box should remove `overflow-wrap: break-word;`?

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```html
<script>
const x = document.querySelector('#disableOverflowWrap');
x.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const y = document.querySelector('p');
  y.removeProperty('overflow-wrap');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Elements don’t have a `removeProperty` method. Even if you targeted the correct object — the element’s `style` property — `removeProperty` would only remove the property directly added to the `style` attribute, not the one applied via a style sheet. Why not simply add a CSS class with only `overflow-wrap: break-word;` and use [`.classList.toggle`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)?

Comment: You want to remove it from the style entirely? Or just one element?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To be honest I'm not sure which option I need, but I think it should be removed completely. The same way as you simply open the file and place the target line inside `/* ... */`.

Comment: Put it another way: Do you want it to affect all `p` elements, or just one? Second question: Are you going to want to restore it if they untick the checkbox?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The wrapper is indeed consists of 3 `p` element, not 1. There are no other `p` in the document. Yes, I want to remove it from all of them. And yes, I want to restore it later when I press the check box again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments you've said you want the checkbox to toggle the setting off and on, and you want the change to affect all `p` elements in the wrapper.

I'd do that by toggling a class on `#wrapper` (or `body`) that overrides the class on `p`, like this:

```js
const cb = document.getElementById("disableOverflowWrap");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
cb.addEventListener('click', ({currentTarget: {checked}}) => {
    wrapper.classList.toggle("override-overflow-wrap", checked);
});
```

```css
#wrapper.override-overflow-wrap p {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
}
```

Live example (I've also added `color: green` to your original rule and `color: black` to the override, to make the change more obvious visually):

```js
const cb = document.getElementById("disableOverflowWrap");
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
cb.addEventListener('click', ({currentTarget: {checked}}) => {
    wrapper.classList.toggle("override-overflow-wrap", checked);
});
```

```css
p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
    color: green;
}
#wrapper.override-overflow-wrap p {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
    <p>Third paragraph</p>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="disableOverflowWrap">
    <label for="disableOverflowWrap">Disable p { overflow-wrap: break-word; }</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested all the solutions here and your solution is actually the best for me. Could you say please what does `cb` mean? Also, another question, I see that you use both single and double quotes. Is it by accident or you mix them intentionally, i.e. use single quotes for purely JavaScript things and double quotes for HTML?

Comment: @jsv - `cb` stands for checkbox. :-) The quotes thing was by accident, I always use `"` by default and only use `'` if I have to for some specific reason. That's because I write a fair bit of English-only software (so I don't need to do i18n) and English uses apostrophes in text, so defaulting to `"` just makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another class `.break-word` which contains the property `word-break: break-word` and remove the class with javascript.

```html
<style>
  p {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
  }
  .break-word {
    background: red;
    word-break: break-word;
  }
  a:any-link {
    hyphens: none;
  }
</style>

<div id="wrapper">
  <p class="break-word">Here goes some text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="disableOverflowWrap">
  <label for="disableOverflowWrap">Disable p { overflow-wrap: break-word; }</label>
</div>

<script>
const x = document.querySelector('#disableOverflowWrap');
x.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const y = document.querySelector('p');
  y.classList.remove('break-word');
});
</script>
```

Comment: This works, thanks, I will probably mark it as answered later. But the file is intended to be read by humans in raw form, and so I'm not really happy with altering CSS.

Comment: Instead of all this why not just set `y.style.overflowWrap = "normal";`?

Comment: @silencedogood This indeed might be a good and simple solution. I need some time to test it.

Answer (score -1):

The `overflowWrap` property is available from the style object, just set it to `normal`:

```
<script>
const x = document.querySelector('#disableOverflowWrap');
x.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
      
      for(let i=0; i < ps.length; i++) {
          ps[i].style.overflowWrap = "normal";
      }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Modified to account for multiple `<p>` tags.